# batch script: Copy to a network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy, network-drive

I'm trying to copy a bunch of folders to a network drive but I am having trouble doing so. Everyone on the network can see this drive, under "my computer" it appears has M:

This use to work fine for me and was a mixed result for other people.

Now when I run it it doesn't copy everything in the "target" folder (It doesn't copy a folder named "surefire-reports", which is present before the copyResult section is called) and nothing is being copied over to the M:

This is the part of the batch that does the copying:

```
:CopyResults
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH_ORIGINAL%
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a-%%b-%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

set source="target"
set Archive= "Archived Results\Test Results - %CLIENTCHOICE% %mydate% At %mytime% Using %BROWSEROPTION%"
set ScreenshotDestination= "Archived Results\Test Results - %CLIENTCHOICE% %mydate% At %mytime% Using %BROWSEROPTION%\Screenshots"
mkdir %Archive%
echo %Archive%
echo d | xcopy %source% %Archive% /k /e /d /y /h /i

rem copy screenshots
set screenshots="Screenshots"
echo d | xcopy %screenshots% %ScreenshotDestination% /k /e /d /y /h /i

rem open the report
%Archive%\site\index.html

rem copy accross to M:
set Destination= "M:\ProductTesting\AutomationResults\%CLIENTCHOICE%\%mydate% At %mytime% Using %BROWSEROPTION% Ran By %username%"
set ScreenshotDestination= "M:\ProductTesting\AutomationResults\%CLIENTCHOICE%\%mydate% At %mytime% Using %BROWSEROPTION% Ran By %username%\Screenshots"
set source2=%Archive%
mkdir %Destination%
echo %Destination%
echo d | xcopy %source2% %Destination% /k /e /d /y /h /i

rem copy screenshots
set screenshots="Screenshots"
echo d | xcopy %screenshots% %ScreenshotDestination% /k /e /d /y /h /i
GOTO end
```

Can anybody see what is going wrong with the copy? Why wouldn't it copy the surefire-reports folder? I thought maybe I need to run the batch file has an admin but when I do that it doesn't open in the correct folder and as everybody will have this batch file in different locations on their computer I don't know how I can change directory to the location the batch is located.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Drives are mapped by user token. Run as Admin is a different token. So mapping a drives unelevated are only available to unelevated programs. Mapping a drive elevated it is only available to elevated programs.

Comment: Sorry Tony I don't understand what you are saying. Do I need to run it has admin? Can I do that in the batch file? If I write click and run as admin it opens in system32 so all my directories are wrong but I can't hardcode them in the batch script because everybody has them in different locations on their computers.

Comment: All your variables have a leading space, probably won't matter most of the time. Your paths are long which will hit the 255 characterlimit for length of a path component (out of 260 characters allowed for the whole path). And as I said drives mapped unelevatedaren't available elevated. Windows has inbuilt variables to refer to locations that change like %userprofile%.